# Facebook graph api not getting post reach

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FB Graph API to get the post reach posted on a page.  But the API always returns an empty data object (no errors).

Query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/[POST_ID]/insights?metric=post_impressions_unique&access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Response:

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/[POST_ID]/insights?access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]&metric=post_impressions_unique&since=1528268400&until=1528441200",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/[POST_ID]/insights?access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]&metric=post_impressions_unique&since=1528614000&until=1528786800"
   }
}
```

I have tried it with other API versions v2.11, v2.12 and v3.0 etc. same response. And posts do have a reach metric when checked on the page.

Anyone have any clue about whats wrong here?

Comment: What permissions does the user access token that was used to get the page token include? What role does that user have on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) 's comment pointed me in the right direction.

My app that I used to get page access token didn't have the **read_insights** permission.

1. From [Graph api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) , from the dropdown "Graph API Explorer" in the top right, I selected my app.
2. From "Get token" dropdown just below it, select "Get App Token".
3. From the popup window make sure you have the **read_insights** permission ticked along with others.